# Use of trailing characters in JAVA/C++

Tags: java

I was bit curious that why we use trailing character in **Java/C++**. Like,

```
float f = 23f;
```

we can also write

```
float f = 23;
```

both having same effect.

Comment: 23 is an int that must be converted to float.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is important when you are hardcoding numbers in mathematical operations.

For example:

```
5 / 2 == 2
5.0f / 2.0f = 2.5f
5.0 / 2.0 = 2.5      // without the 'f' suffix you have doubles
5.0d / 2.0d = 2.5d   // for doubles 'd' can be used as well
```

Also these will have a different result:

```
blah / 3.141592653592  // this returns an accurate double
blah / 3.141592653592f // this returns a less accurate float
```

Comment: Suffixes can be written only on one side.

Comment: @MarounMaroun: I know, it is a style preference :) What I want to do with my code is "dividing two floats", so I write it like that. Otherwise the code would look like "divide an int by a float" or vise versa.

Comment: Seems worth pointing out in the accepted answer that f and d are fine, but longs should be represented with a capital L to avoid confusion (e.g., 100l looks like 1001 while 100L is clear).

Answer (score 1):

This is because there is something else that can supply the type information in the second case (namely, the type of the variable). In cases like that suffixes are not required.

However, you may need them in other cases, when the type information must be derived from the numeric literal itself. For example, consider the two expressions below:

```
float f = 23 / 5;  // Integer division
```

vs.

```
float f = 23f / 5; // Floating point division
```

You would get different results with and without the suffix.

Answer (score 0):

They have the same effect, but there is an extra step in the second.  The data type of `23` is `int`.  The compiler almost certainly converts `23` to a float at compile time, but it does have to check that the number can be represented as a float.  They take the same amount of space, so some integers can't be represented as floats.  Consider this Java code:

```
int i   = 2147483647; // Integer.MAX_VALUE, but at compile time.
System.out.println(i);

float f = 2147483647; // Integer.MAX_VALUE, but at compile time.
System.out.println(f);
```

What gets printed?